# website url can access with or without index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have removed index.php from URL in Codeigniter. But I can access URL with both ways like.

abc.com/index.php/123

abc.com/123

But I need if somebody type abc.com/index.php/123 it will be redirected to the abc.com/123

What I did below code i written in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

And in config.php i have removed index.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

But still i can open url with both ways

Comment: you can do this with .htaccess file

Comment: I have already done but its not working . Please writ solution or give demo

Comment: _"I have already done but its not working"_ - Then you didn't do it correctly. Please show us your attempt. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you show us the code you used in your .htaccess file? It's best to learn from your mistakes :)

Comment: I have done this https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-htaccess/

Comment: You have enough rep and have been here long enough to know that you need to include your attempts in your question.

Comment: Hi I have edit my question please check

Comment: So now what will you say

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Hi can you check now

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Please check now

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache redirects inside your `.htaccess` file or inside your `<VirtualHost *:80>` block, in your case this might look like:

`RedirectMatch /index.php/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1`

Also, here's a nice guide on using them https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache-tips-and-tricks/redirect-urls-with-the-apache-web-server/

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Include the actual solution into the answer and only have the link as a reference. It that link changes/gets removed, this answer won't be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: I have posted the solution on the first line, exactly what he was asking for. The guide is if he wants to learn more about how to use apache redirects or setting it up

Comment: You only gave an abstract example. Please modify it to fit the OP's needs and also explain _where_ the OP should put this. If not, then the OP (or future visitors) might still need to visit the link, or google, about how to actually use it. See SO as a class room and you need to explain in detail how to solve the equations.

Comment: ok added information on where to insert the code. Thanks

Comment: Can i do it with php without using htaccess

Comment: It can be done from PHP using ```header("Location: http://example.com/...");``` but I would suggest in your case where you are trying to enforce a global redirect it is far better done from apache. Just to add, your rewriterule appears to be backwards - it redirects everything to index.php rather than away from it.

Comment: @NickMiles : I have done with htaccess but i can access url with both ways